# Android 4.+ NumberPicker - Forcing Number Keyboard Layout

Tags: android, numberpicker

Am posting this in hopes to help someone else; but, if there is an easier way to do the same, I hope someone can share their steps. If I use the method 'setDisplayedValues' to pass an array of values to display in the NumberPicker, the underlying method forces the use of a Text Keyboard Layout, instead of the Number Layout, which isn't what I want.
I found a way to set the InputType for my NumberPicker. This is done in my extended class:

**class public class NumberPickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment**:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // We are getting the parameters passed in to figure out the range of the Number Picker
    NumPickerValues = getArguments().getStringArray("NumPickerRange");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    View dlgNumPicker = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_num_picker, null);
    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) dlgNumPicker.findViewById(R.id.npNumberPicker);
    // Always remember that NumberPicker methods need an index position, rather than the value in that array position
    np.setMinValue(0);
    np.setMaxValue(NumPickerValues.length-1);
    np.setDisplayedValues(NumPickerValues);
    np.setValue(getArguments().getInt("InitialValue"));
    np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);
    np.setOnValueChangedListener(this);
    // Since the underlying code for the NumberPicker sets the keyboard layout for text, due to the use of 'setDisplayedValues',
    // we need to set it back to a number keyboard layout
    ((EditText)np.getChildAt(0)).setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
    return builder.setView(dlgNumPicker)
            .setTitle(getArguments().getInt("NumPickerTitle"))
            .setPositiveButton(getArguments().getInt("SaveButtonTitle"), new ButtonCLickListener())
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new ButtonCLickListener())
            .create();
}
```

On the section of code above, the line that sets the InputType is
**((EditText)np.getChildAt(0)).setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);**

I didn't find anything on the web that does this. It seems like a clean way of doing it; but, am not sure if there is any performance issues by doing it this way. If there is, let us know.